# Windows 7 ODBC driver

Tags: windows, ms-access, odbc, microstation

I need to create a datasource for Microstation V7 in Windows 7(64bit), but I can't find "Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)" ODBC driver.I looked in Control Panel>Administrative Tools>Datasources(ODBC) and when I click the "add" button in the User DSN I only see "SQL Server" and "SQL Native Server". Where is Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb) or how can I install it?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a 32/64 bit problem.

I assume Microstation is a 64-bit program and Office are 32-bit applications. This mismatch is hard to overcome.

Maybe [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/odbc-3264-bit-dilemma/87d15d67-5345-4096-a479-a3d6549bf500) answers your question.